# Why does a custom \todonotes \newcommand interfere with bibtex?

Tags: macros, bibtex, todonotes

I'm using the `\todonotes` package and I have defined various custom notes, following an answer I got from here e.g. `\newcommand{\todoinline}[2][1=]{\todo[inline,#1]{#2}}` (and can't find anymore now).

This all used to work perfectly when I last used it intesively 2 years ago but now I have two problems:

- It throws errors (but still works):

  ```
   Package xkeyval Error: `1' undefined in families `todonotes'. \todoinline{Test inline}
  ```
- And it breaks my bibliography, I only get

  ```
  Citation `McLorem2022' on page 2 undefined
  ```

  errors for every single citation.

**How can I use custom `\todonotes` without breaking bibtex?**

If use `\todo[inline]{something}` instead of my custom command, it all works flawlessly, but I'd like to have a shorthand for it in autocomplete and some color coding for different notes.

When producing a MWE (see below), it also works (apart from the error), but with a real file, I can reproducible get bibtex to fail/work by replacing `\todo[inline]{something}` with `\todoinline{something}` but I'm at my wits end trying to figure out what's causing it.

*file.tex, I added all other possible causes:*

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{natbib}

\newcommand{\todogreen}[2][1=]{\todo[color=green,#1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\todored}[2][1=]{\todo[color=red,#1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\todoblue}[2][1=]{\todo[inline, color=cyan,#1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\todoinline}[2][1=]{\todo[inline,#1]{#2}}

\title{My cool article}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Something important
\end{abstract}
\section{Main text}
"Lorem ipsum" \citep{McLorem2022}. Isotopes: \ce{^{18}O} and \ce{^{2}H}.
\todoinline{Test inline}
\todored{Test red}
\todogreen{Test green}
\todoblue{Test blue}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{testimage.png}
    \caption{Some image}
    \todo[inline]{Should be improved}
    \label{fig:someimage}
\end{figure}
See also Fig. \ref{fig:someimage}!
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{l p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth}}
        \toprule
        A & B  \\
        \midrule
        1 & 2 \\
        4 & 4 $\dagger$ \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    $\dagger$ some hint
    \caption{Simple table}
    \label{table:simple_table}
\end{table}
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\bibliography{mybib.bib}
\end{document}
```

*mybib.bib:*

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{McLorem2022,
    author  = {Mc Lorem, Ipsum},
    journal = {Invented Words},
    title   = {A novel way to invent silly words},
    year    = {2022},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

Comment: If you never use the first optional argument for your custom commands anyway (`\todoinline[shadow]{Test inline}` for example) then you can also remove that from your definitions and just use `\newcommand{\todoinline}[1]{\todo[inline]{#1}}`. I don't know if that would also solve your BibTeX issue as this is apparently not reproducible from your MWE (so probably not, there could be some sort of interaction between `todonotes` and BibTeX in your real document that is not present in the MWE).

Comment: I just adapted some code snippet and I'm not 100% familiar with `\newcommand` and as it worked perfectly fine, I just kept it.

Comment: Turns out, this was the issue! If I change all my custom todos to just one argument, as per your comment, it works! Can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optional argument in the custom todonotes definitions does not seem to be used. You can simplify the definitions therefore as follows:

```
\newcommand{\todogreen}[1]{\todo[color=green]{#1}}
\newcommand{\todored}[1]{\todo[color=red]{#1}}
\newcommand{\todoblue}[1]{\todo[inline, color=cyan]{#1}}
\newcommand{\todoinline}[1]{\todo[inline]{#1}}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{natbib}

\newcommand{\todogreen}[1]{\todo[color=green]{#1}}
\newcommand{\todored}[1]{\todo[color=red]{#1}}
\newcommand{\todoblue}[1]{\todo[inline, color=cyan]{#1}}
\newcommand{\todoinline}[1]{\todo[inline]{#1}}

\title{My cool article}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Something important
\end{abstract}
\section{Main text}
"Lorem ipsum" \citep{McLorem2022}. Isotopes: \ce{^{18}O} and \ce{^{2}H}.
\todoinline{Test inline}
\todored{Test red}
\todogreen{Test green}
\todoblue{Test blue}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Some image}
    \todo[inline]{Should be improved}
    \label{fig:someimage}
\end{figure}
See also Fig. \ref{fig:someimage}!
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{l p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth}}
        \toprule
        A & B  \\
        \midrule
        1 & 2 \\
        4 & 4 $\dagger$ \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    $\dagger$ some hint
    \caption{Simple table}
    \label{table:simple_table}
\end{table}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\bibliography{todobib.bib}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

According to a [comment by the OP](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630855/why-does-a-custom-todonotes-newcommand-interfere-with-bibtex?noredirect=1#comment1573267_630855) these redefinitions also solve the original issue.